# JAXB2 adding xmlns to XML output

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces

I saw that this has been asked other time and I've reviewed the answer but I should admit that I'm still not able to get the desired output :(
Now what I would like to have is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tokenregistrationrequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="TOKEN">
    <purchase>true</purchase>
</tokenregistrationrequest>
```

My class definition look like the following:

```
@XmlRootElement() //THIS HAS BEEN ADDED MANUALLY
public class Tokenregistrationrequest {
    protected boolean purchase;
}
```

and I've modified the package-info like the following:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(xmlns = {
    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "xsi", namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "xs", namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"),
    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "", namespaceURI = "TOKEN")
})
```

When I'm running the code what I got is just...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tokenregistrationrequest>
    <purchase>true</purchase>
</tokenregistrationrequest>
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something basic here... 
Any help would greatly appreciated

EDIT: while doing some more test I've seen that when compiling my test class JAXB artifact are compiled but NOT package-info.java. Is this because the usage of this is optional?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since the question asked, but i just found myself in a similar situation. It's a bit disturbing but it's possible with this way if you really insist of it.

You just can add these properties manually as an attribute to your entity class.

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "xmlns")
private String token = "TOKEN";

@XmlAttribute(name = "xmlns:xsd")
private String schema = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";

@XmlAttribute(name = "xmlns:xsi")
private String schemaInstance = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
```

Then you should get this as output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tokenregistrationrequest xmlns="TOKEN" 
                          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <purchase>true</purchase>
</tokenregistrationrequest>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Annotation XmlNs on package Level binds a prefix to a Namespace. However, if the Namespace is not used, like in your case, the Namespace nodes will not be added to the root-element.

You propably should put the Tokenregistrationrequest in the TOKEN Namespace:

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "TOKEN") //THIS HAS BEEN ADDED MANUALLY
public class Tokenregistrationrequest {

    protected boolean purchase;
```

This will result in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tokenregistrationrequest xmlns="TOKEN">
    <purchase>true</purchase>
</tokenregistrationrequest>
```

The rest of the prefix declarations won't appear, as there are no nodes from those namespaces in the resulting document. If there were any, the prefix declarations should also be serialized.

Comment: I see... but what's more odd is that if I compile my test class everything is compiled but package-info.java. I'm starting to think that that is not really considered...
Additionally if I do what you suggested I got out something like this: "<ns2:tokenregistrationrequest xmlns:ns2="TOKEN">"

Comment: If the package-info isn't compiled the annotations wont be available to the Jaxb-Context at runtime. How do you compile anyways? Also there seems to be a difference in how JAXB-Providers are regarding these Annotations, maybe you could try using Moxy instead of the Default Provider.

Comment: So far only via command line... no decent IDE available or ant or anything else. Anyway you're right after compilation I got same as your sample. So there's no way to add the standard xsd and xsi namespace?

Comment: Well there possibly is, but it would not be using it as intended. The Marshaller writes all Information there is to an object as XML. The prefix Definition is not an Information, because the prefix is not used. Why do you need them anyways?

Comment: And just to be clear, these are no "namespaces you add to the document"! It's more like a shortcut "if I write xsd:schema I mean the Schema element from the http://.../Xml-Schema Namespace" So the Logic is, if you don't need that shortcut, why add it?

Comment: Agree with you but I'm constrained by a specification that ask those elements to be present.

Comment: That's a hassle, the receiver of that document most certainly doesnt need them, maybe you can talk him out of it. If not, you can always add these after marshalling using dom, text-Manipulation, xslt, or whatever, which is imho still way cleaner than hacking the jaxb-marshaller.